# Complex Loop with limited iterations and IF statement

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, joptionpane

The loop needs to scan an external file, from the bottom to the top. BUT...

When the loop has scanned 6 items from the external file, it needs to stop.

Then, IF there are less than 6 items to scan from the list on the external file it needs to print all of the those items to the screen.

I know how to do a loop that can scan the file from top to bottom using `inFile.hasNext();` etc. I just don't know how to do from bottom to top and then define how many iterations I want the loop to actually do, with an if statement that is something like:

```
if (number of iterations < 6 print all) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iteration1, iteration2, etc...)
}`
else if (number of iterations >= 6 only show the first 6 the loop has scanned)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iteration1, iteration2, etc...)
}
```

Sorry about my awful pseudo code, just really stuck and this is the last part I need to do to finish my system!

any help would be brilliant!

Comment: Have you tried setting up a counter to increment with each iteration, and your condition checking its value?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [a predefined class for reading backward](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html). As to looping:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6 && /* test for more input*/; i++)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( /*next input*/ );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try instantiating an array with 6 empty strings and then concatenate the item you get in each iteration of the loop with the corresponding empty string in your array. 
Afterwards you can check for your < 6 condition and depending on the result concatenate the string you want to give to your JOptionPane

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a file from bottom to top. Instead, read the file (top to bottom) keeping the last (up to) 6 items read. When you hit the end if the file, test if you you have 6 items or not and act accordingly.

Use a `LinkedList` object, which allows removal of the element of the list via [`removeFist()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirst()).

You could just store all items and use only the last 6, but that may mean using a lot of memory if the file is very large.